# Ionic 2 reload/refresh comments panel or entire page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a post detail page in my IONIC 2 App and there is a comment section, I want whenever there is an approved comment it shows be seen in the recent comment and for this page needs to be reloaded or comment section need to be updated.

Please suggest me the best approach to complete this:-

My comment form html:-

```
<!-- Comment -->
        <div class="comment">
            <ion-list top_border *ngIf="comments">
                <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let comment of comments">
                    <div img_box>
                        <div thumbnail_img>
                            <img [src]="comment.author_avatar_urls[96]">
                        </div >
                        <div class="tag">
                            <h2>{{comment.author_name}}</h2>
                            <span class="blicon-clock">&nbsp;{{comment.date | date: 'mediumDate'}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p [innerHTML]="comment.content.rendered"></p>
                </ion-item> 
            </ion-list>

            <div id="commentPanel" class="comment_textarea">
                <form (ngSubmit)="PostComment()">
                     <ion-textarea rows="3" [(ngModel)]="usercomment.comment" name="usercomment" placeholder="Write something..."></ion-textarea>
                     <button ion-button>
                      <ion-icon type="submit" ios="ios-arrow-round-forward" md="md-arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Comment -->
```

and here is my post function:-

```
PostComment() {
        let loader = this.loadingController.create({
            content: "Please wait"
        });
        loader.present();

        let commentdata : { post: number, content: string, author_name: string, author_email: string } = {
            post: this.post.id, 
            content: this.usercomment.comment, 
            author_name: this.user.user_display_name, 
            author_email: this.user.user_email
        };

        this.myService.PostComment(commentdata)
        .subscribe((result) => {
                if(result.status == "approved") {
                    loader.dismiss();
                    let toast = this.toastController.create({
                        message: "Your comment has been successfully posted.",
                        duration: 2000
                    });
                    toast.present();
                  // TODO Here to page refers
                } else if(result.status == "hold") {
                    loader.dismiss();
                    let toast = this.toastController.create({
                        message: "Your comment is awaiting approval.",
                        duration: 2000
                    });
                    toast.present();
                } else if(result.message) {
                    loader.dismiss();
                    let toast = this.toastController.create({
                        message: result.message,
                        duration: 2000
                    });
                    toast.present();
                } else {
                    loader.dismiss();
                    let toast = this.toastController.create({
                        message: 'There is something wrong, please try again later.',
                        duration: 2000
                    });
                    toast.present();                    
                }
            this.usercomment.comment = '';
        }, (error) => {
          loader.dismiss();
          let errorMessage = error.json();
          if (errorMessage && errorMessage.message) {
            let message = errorMessage.message.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
            let toast = this.toastController.create({
              message: message,
              duration: 6000,
              position: 'bottom'
            });
            toast.present();
         }
      });
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to refresh page. When the comment is approved, simply push it into comments array.

```
[...]
if(result.status == "approved") {
  loader.dismiss();
  let toast = this.toastController.create({
      message: "Your comment has been successfully posted.",
      duration: 2000
  });
  toast.present();
  this.comments.push(commentdata); 
}
```

Comment: I had no idea this can be done so easily, thank you so much. For me it worked by using this.comments.push(result).